# How to set Rebus transaction context for a web service

Tags: asp.net, web-services, transactions, rebus

Given that I have a web/SOAP service, how do I setup and teardown a proper transaction context for Rebus (the messaging bus)? When Rebus is calling into a message handler this is not a problem since Rebus will setup the transaction context before calling the handler - but what about the opposite where a web service handler needs to send/publish a message via Rebus?

I am not interested in how to implement an HTTP module or similar - only the basics around Rebus: what is needed to prepare Rebus for sending a message?

The web service code has its own transaction going on when talking to the application database. I need to be able to setup Rebus when setting up the database transaction and comit/rollback Rebus when doing the same with the database.

I have a similar problem with standalone command line programs that needs to both interaction with a database and sending Rebus messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rebus will automatically enlist send and publish operations in its own "ambient transaction context", which is accessed via the static(*) `AmbientTransactionContext.Current` property.

You could implement `ITransactionContext` yourself if you wanted to, but Rebus comes with `DefaultTransactionContext` in the box.

You use it like this:

```
using(var context = new DefaultTransactionContext())
{
    AmbientTransactionContext.Current = context;

    // send and publish things in here

    // complete the transaction
    await context.Complete();
}
```

which could easily be put e.g. in an OWIN middleware or something similar.

---

(*) The property is static, but the underlying value is bound to the current execution context (by using `CallContext.LogicalGet/SetData`), which means that you can think of it as thread-bound, with the nice property that it flows as expected to continuations.

In Rebus 2.0.2 it is possible to customize the accessors used to get/set the context by calling `AmbientTransactionContext.SetAccessors(...)` with an `Action<ITransactionContext>` and a `Func<ITransactionContext>`, e.g. like this:

```
AmbientTransactionContext.SetAccessors(
    context => {
        if (HttpContext.Current == null) {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Can't set the transaction context when there is no HTTP context");
        }
        HttpContext.Current.Items["current-rbs-context"] = context
    },
    () => HttpContext.Current?.Items["current-rbs-context"] as ITransactionContext
);
```

which in this case makes it work in a way that flows properly even when using old school HTTP modules ;)

Comment: Thanks. It helped to a certain degree ... for normal synchronous ASP MVC 5 controller methods it works fine: AmbientTransactionContext.Current is the same before and after the controller invocation. But when the controller method is `async Task<ActionResult>` and it does an `await Bus.Publish(msg)` then AmbientTransactionContext.Current is NULL after the controller invocation. AmbientTransactionContext.Current is managed in a HTTP module begin/end-request.

Comment: "AmbientTransactionContext.Current is managed in a HTTP module begin/end-request"
...
That's probably not good then – ASP.NET is known to switch threads at funny times, and apparently is does not guarantee that the web request handler is executed with the same execution context as the HTTP module. You should probably pick another place to establish the context

Comment: Okay, I get the idea. Refactoring now to store the contex in HttpContext.Current.Items. Wondering though if there is something inside Rebus that looks at AmbientTransactionContext.Current and fails? Does the code inside Publish() see two different transactions if I do two Bus.Publish() in one request?

Comment: SO is not for disucssions so I have added an issue on GitHub for this problem: https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/issues/554